# id is right but not value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to alert id of a button (which is generated using jquery ) but when i alert its value it not coming right. heres the code

```
function removeimg(name,btn12){        
        //make request to remove the name
       // $("#" + name).closest('li').remove();
      //  $("#" + btn12).remove();
       // document.getElementById(name).style.display = 'none';
       // document.getElementById(btn12).style.display = 'none';
       var str = "#" + btn12;
       alert(str);
       alert($(str).val());


    }
```

here is the link

http://shri-ram.lifekloud.com/pilot/step4.php

when you uplaod a image under the tab "add delete photo" the button is generated

Comment: just reading the question it's obvious you are looking at 2 different things. How would ID and value be the same based on what little code you provided?

Comment: how is your button markup looks like .. is it `<input type="button"` or `<button></button>`

Comment: try `alert($(str).length)` to see if selector even matches an element. Demo link is far too involved for anyone to do much to help. Create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem

Comment: i just cheked it and the lenght is 0

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Checked out my code.? It should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one meta-character `.` in your id `#btnheader-8878374.png`, That is the problem.

Just escape like this

```
$('.#btnheader-8878374\\.png')
```

and try you will get your concept working.

Full code,

```
var str = "#" + btn12;
str = str.replace('.','\\\\');
alert($(str).val());
```

Answer (score 3):

> i am trying to alert id of a button

[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) does not get the id of an element; `val` returns the value element.

To get the id of an element, use `attr`

```
alert($(str).attr('id'));
```

---

Just a stab in the dark from your comment `well its not even returning value thts the issue. but the id name is getting displayed correctly`

If you have

```
<input type='button' id='b' value='btn' />
```

then

```
alert($('#b').val());
```

will in fact display `btn`.  That said, if you have

```
<button id='b'>btn</button>
```

then nothing will be displayed.  But like I said that's just a stab in the dark.  It's impossible to know better without the html available (and I'm afraid I don't have time to parse through your site)

Comment: +1, although I don't think @AbhishekKumar meaned this, as he already has the id of the element (`str` in his code).

Comment: @WouterJ entirely possible.  That said, I've seen stranger things in these parts :)

Comment: well its not even returning value thts the issue. but the id name is getting displayed correctly

Comment: @AbhishekKumar: If I understood correctly, you are trying to get a button element by id and display its value. The code looks fine in that case, but the actual button markup is missing in your question, so it is difficult to say for sure.

Comment: pls cheek the link i mentioned and try to upload one image every thing will be clear

Comment: pls chek the lnik i mentioned and uplaodone image the button has a value "Remove"

Comment: is . (period) not allowed in a jquery id name?

Comment: @AbhishekKumar yes, that's not allowed. That is the class selector

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely that you do not have the `value` attribute set on your buttons, thus calling [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) returns nothing.

If you want the text of the button just call [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

### [See jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KBgZ7/)

---

### HTML

```
<button id="btn12">Button 12</button>
```

---

### JQUERY

```
var str = "#" + "btn12";

alert( str );             // yields #btn12
alert( $(str).val() );    // yields nothing
alert( $(str).text() );   // yields Button 12
```